# ASCII characters

Tags: c

I'm doing a homework assignment in which I need to print out to the console and a text file the numbers 0-255 along with the Hex and Ascii which goes along with them.

The main focus of the assignment is to learn about formatting and file handling.

I've figured out all the nice formatting by using widths and I can print things out to the file no problem.

I'm using `%d %X %c` for my `printf()`.

My pet peeve is that ASCII 11, 12 and 13(???) are something like tab, lf and some other non-image char.

This totally screws with those two rows and I'm a wee bit anal about stuff like this.

Is there a fast and easy way to get something else to show up that won't screw with my columns and rows or do I need to put in `if`-statements and filter these guys out myself?

Comment: You probably should be printing only printable characters in the ASCII range, not the control characters or other non-glyph characters.  It sounds perfectly reasonable to print them as spaces.

Comment: Thanks all.  I'll do some reading and modify my code.

Comment: 128-255 do not represent ASCII characters. If you are printing them then you should find out what they mean in the encoding you are using (which probably isn't ASCII). It's possible that they don't mean anything (e.g., 129 in Windows-1252). If you can output to a console or file with UTF-8 encoding, you can use Unicode's [Control Pictures](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf)(␀ ... ␟, ...) in place of unprintable characters. (That also requires that your console or file viewer/editor uses a font that can display them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to filter out things you don't want to print yourself.

To help with that, look into the [`isgraph`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/isgraph.html) and the other `is*` functions. They should help you along pretty well.

Comment: maybe isprint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewx8s4kw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx do exactly what is needed

Answer (score 1):

Most of the bottom characters are not printable. You'll have to print something else. The best thing I can think is create an array of strings for lowest 32 chars, which are problematic and print from the lowest 32 from there while you use the normal print for the others (but yes, you need some kind of if).

Answer (score 1):

These characters are called ["Control Characters"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) and will be difficult to print if you only assign one single character space for them.

You should be able to catch all of these with a call to [`iscntrl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/iscntrl.html) and print something more convenient in their place.